# C++ fstream Won't Find Relative Path

Tags: c++, file, fstream

The problem is below. I am using Microsoft Visual Studio and admissions.txt is in the same folder as the .cpp, .h, and .sln files, yet the program can't find the relative path. Explicitly stating the path doesn't work either. I am just concerned with getting the ifstream working right now.

```
/*
A new aquarium just opened up and your boss would like you to write a short program that allows him / her to calculate the number of tickets sold and money brought in for ticket sales.
There are different types of tickets you can buy : All - Access, Gold, and Silver.
The data for ticket sales will be stored in the file admissions.txt with the following format where the first column represents the ticket cost and the second the number of tickets sold.
150.00 89
56.50 300
45.25 450

The first line indicates that the ticket price is $150.00 and that 89 tickets were sold at that price.Output the total number of tickets sold and the total sale amount for ALL tickets.Format your output with two decimal places.

Sample input file :
226 1761
153 28513
62 35779

*/

include fstream
include iostream
include string

using namespace std;


int main()
{

    ifstream inFileData;

    string line1;
    string line2;
    string line3;

    inFileData.open("admissions.txt"); //contains sample input

    inFileData >> line1;
    inFileData >> line2;
    inFileData >> line3;

    cout << line1;
    cout << line2;
    cout << line3;

    inFileData.close();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Make sure that the `admissions.txt` file exists in your programs current working directory.

Comment: _"and admissions.txt is in the same folder as the .cpp, .h, and .sln files"_ That's not where the resulting executable will be placed and executed by default.

Comment: [Helpful reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)

Comment: More to @πάνταῥεῖ point, when run from the integrated debugger, the default current working directory for a program is the *project* folder (i.e. where the .vcxproj file is located). You can verify this by checking the project properties. Right-click your project in the solution explorer pane, select "Properties", select "Debugging" in the properties editor left-pane tree, see the "Working Directory" setting in the right pane. The default value is `$(ProjectDir)`, which means the directory of the .vcxproj file. You can change it at said-same setting if desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this program to generate a test file. Whereever it generates said file, your input file has to be. In my case, it is relative to the .vcxproj for the VS debugger and in the same directory as the .exe when using the .exe.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream file("relative_path_test.txt");

    if (file.is_open()) {
        file << "Test file";
    }

    file.close();

    return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

add a `system("dir")` to your program to see the path to the directory you are in when the program runs.  From there you should be able to figure out what the correct path to the file is.

Comment: Or a `system ("cd")`